# Selecting rows containing specific int stored in set column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have tried and searched on web and am giving up... I would like to ask you for help with following (I am using Python 3 and Pandas):

Imagine df with the VALUES column containing integers in the sets:

In:

```
            VALUES
0           {2624, 1383, 2855, 1871, 16784, 9811, 2970}
1           {2898, 12, 1871, 223}
2           {2624, 2855, 519, 15662, 1230, 1871, 2970}
3          {2624, 12, 55, 519, 313, 1230, 10588, 2970}
4           {1230, 55, 89564, 1247}
```

Out desired (only the rows containing specific value e.g. 12 in sets in VALUES, everything else dropped):

```
            VALUES
1           {2898, 12, 1871, 223}
3          {2624, 12, 55, 519, 313, 1230, 10588, 2970}
```

In next step, I will need to move int 12 to new separate column. Also, I could not find a way how to convert these sets in lists.

```
               VALUES                                  NEW_COL
1           [2898, 1871, 223]                             12
3          [2624, 55, 519, 313, 1230, 10588, 2970]        12
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to **break down your problem into smaller, easier steps**:

- 1. select rows with the desired values
- 2. create a new dataframe with the selected rows
- 3. add a new column with the value
- 4. filter the "VALUES" column to remove the value you are looking for

Taking your example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "VALUES": [
    (2624, 1383, 2855, 1871, 16784, 9811, 2970),
    (2898, 12, 1871, 223),
    (2624, 2855, 519, 15662, 1230, 1871, 2970),
    (2624, 12, 55, 519, 313, 1230, 10588, 2970),
    (1230, 55, 89564, 1247)
] 
})
```

select the rows with the desired value `val`:

```
val = 12

b = df["VALUES"].apply(lambda tup: val in tup)
df2 = df.loc[b].copy()
```

create a new column `"NEW_COL"` and filter out `val` from the `"VALUES"` column:

```
df2["NEW_COL"] = val
df2["VALUES"] = df2["VALUES"].apply(lambda values: [v for v in values if v != val])
```

### wrapping it all in 1 function

```
def create_df(df: pd.DataFrame, val: int, col_name_value = "VALUES", col_name_new = "NEW_COL"):
    b = df[col_name_value].apply(lambda tup: val in tup)
    df2 = df.loc[b].copy()
    df2[col_name_new] = val
    df2[col_name_value] = df2[col_name_value].apply(lambda values: [v for v in values if v != val])
    return df2
```

You get the desired output:

```
create_df(df, 12)
```

[image]

```
create_df(df, 2624)
```

[image]

Comment: this looks promissing... I do not understand why I have {} after using .apply(set) in previous steps. The code was: df["COLUMN"] = df["COLUMN"].apply(set)...

Comment: Thanks a lot! When you are in Prague I will buy you a beer.

Comment: You can select my post as the abswer and upvote it. Same as being me a beer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Filter for matches :

```py
booleans = [12 in val for val in df.VALUES]
out = df.loc[booleans]
```

Remove 12 from VALUES to get final output:

```py
out.assign(VALUES = out.VALUES - {12}, NEW_COL = 12)

                                    VALUES  NEW_COL
1                        {2898, 1871, 223}       12
3  {2624, 519, 1230, 55, 313, 2970, 10588}       12
```

if you want to convert to list:

```py
out.assign(VALUES = (out.VALUES - {12}).map(list), NEW_COL = 12)
                                    VALUES  NEW_COL
1                        [2898, 1871, 223]       12
3  [2624, 519, 1230, 55, 313, 2970, 10588]       12
```

I'm not sure what you are working on, but performance wise, it is better to deal with structures such as list/sets/tuples... outside Pandas